# How to create a vector for coordinate transformation?

Tags: coordinate-system, affine-transformation

Very new to geospatial data here. I have a number of satellite images with lower left and upper right corner points in 3857. When I lay these images in QGIS against Google's satellite imagery, I'm recognizing that the images don't exactly line up and have determined that the initial coordinates I have that correspond to my initial images are probably slightly incorrect.

I would like to transform these coordinates in some way to correct the location of the image. What is a way to do this?

Currently I am grabbing a landmark (a corner of a building roof for example) in the 'incorrect' image and getting the Lat/Lon. Then in Google's satellite image, I'm grabbing the same landmark which will have the 'correct' Lat/Lon. It's imprecise but sufficient. I just need to figure out how to create a transform matrix from these two points so I can apply this same transformation to all coordinates within my images. Is it safe to simply subtract the degree differences between the two corner points and apply this across all corner points?

Comment: Are your images exactly straight overhead? How big are the regions they depict? Are you sure it is EPSG:3857 (some kind of "meters") and not EPSG:4326 (lat lon)?

Comment: Yes, I've converted from 4326 to 3857, trying to get the meters as precise as visually possible. My assumption is they are directly overhead. Each of the images (tiled) looks to be covering ~ 300sq meters